# Why can't I use this instead of a object in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code A works well! In Code B, I think ***this*** will point to ***$('#SelectImageFilter')***, but in fact, Code B failed, why?

**Code A**

```
$("#SelectImageFilter").change(function () {
            temp.imagefilter = $('#SelectImageFilter').get(0).selectedIndex;        

});
```

**Code B**

```
$("#SelectImageFilter").change(function () {
            temp.imagefilter = this.get(0).selectedIndex;        

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this does not point to $('#SelectImageFilter'). it actually points to  $('#SelectImageFilter')[0] or  $('#SelectImageFilter').get(0) in this case.

this points to javascript DOM element, use $(this) if  you want it to point to jQuery object

Change Code B to

```
$("#SelectImageFilter").change(function () {
        temp.imagefilter = this.selectedIndex;        
});
```